# Prove that $(A,*)$ is a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra

$F$ is a field.

$A$ is defined as the group of all the functions from $\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$ to $F$.

Let's define a binary operation $*$ on $A$ as follows:

For all $f,g\in A$ the function $f*g\in A$ is defined by: $(n)f*g=\sum_{k=0}^n (k)f(n-k)g$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Please help me prove that $(A,*)$ is a monoid.

**Second part (added lately):**

Let us say that a function $f\in A$ has a *finite support* if the set $\{n \mid (n)f\ne 0\}$ is finite. Let $B$ be the set of all the functions in $A$ with a finite support.

Prove that $B$ is a subsemigroup of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: We can think of elements of $A$ as infinite sequence of elements of $\mathbf{F}$. If $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, then $x*y=\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where

$$z_n=\sum_{k=0}^nx_ky_{n-k}\;.$$

Clearly $A$ is closed under $*$, and it’s not hard to see what the identity element is. HINT: Its first term is $1_{\mathbf{F}}$.

The hardest work is proving that $*$ is associative. 
Let $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, and $z=\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be arbitrary elements of $A$, and let $x*y=\langle u_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $y*z=v=\langle v_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Then the $n$-th term of $(x*y)*z=u*z$ is

$$\sum_{k=0}^nu_kz_{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{i=0}^kx_iy_{k-i}\right)z_{n-k}\;,$$

the $n$-th term of $x*(y*z)=x*v$ is

$$\sum_{k=0}^nx_kv_{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^nx_k\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}y_iz_{k-i}\right)\;,$$

and the problem is to show that they are equal. To do this, show that both double summations are equal to

$$\sum\{x_iy_jz_k:0\le i,j,k\le n\text{ and }i+j+k=n\}\;.$$

**Added:** For each sequence $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in B$ there is a minimal $m_x\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n=0$ for all $n\ge m_x$. To show that $B$ is closed under $*$, show that $m_{x*y}\le m_x+m_y$.

Comment: @Ran: Using the hint that I gave, suppose that the identity element is $e=\langle 1,e_1,e_2,\ldots\rangle$, and compute a few terms of $e*x$. The first term is $1\cdot x_0=x_0$, which is what we want. The second term is $1\cdot x_1+e_1\cdot x_0=x_1+e_1\cdot x_0$, and we want it to be $x_1$; what does that tell you about $e_1$? Try another term or two, and you should see the pattern.

Comment: @Ran: I added a hint for the one part of the addition that might cause trouble.

Comment: Thank you, but how can we show that $m_{x*y}\le m_x+m_y$? Maybe you meant $m_{x*y}\le m_x*m_y$?

Comment: @Ran: No, I meant what I wrote. If $n\ge m_x+m_y$, every term $x_ky_{n-k}$ is $0$.